# HttpPostedFileBase is Null Every Time

Tags: c#, file, asp.net-core-mvc

I saw many questions like this and searched through all the other cases on StackOverflow for an answer to why this is the case and none of them applied. Everything I can see is correct so far. My name for the file input tag is exactly the same as the variable name on the create method in the controller. I even added the enctype to the form. See below:

HTML:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm(new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <p><input type="file" name="file" id="file" /></p>
        <p><input type="submit" value="Update" class="btn btn-default" /></p>
    </div>
}
```

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create(HttpPostedFileBase file) // This is where it's NULL
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            IO io = new IO();
            if (file != null)
            {
                UpdateLog updateLog = io.updateIt(file);
                db.UpdateLogs.Add(updateLog);
                db.SaveChanges();
            } else
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Create");
            }


            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return View();
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

I discovered that the Html.BeginForm method requires 3 arguments in the cshtml. I had to manually specify the method and controller.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "UpdateLogs", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
```